# Scroll to bottom when not visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

I can scroll div to bottom by setting its `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight`. But it only works when this div is visible. How do I make this work when `display: none`?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br></div>
<button onclick="div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight">scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` only works in the context of a visible element in the browser window.

Comment: What do I do then?

Comment: It exists in memory. But, doesn't interact. You can't do nothing!